# Problem inserting string or NULL into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble coming up with the proper syntax for allowing either a string or a NULL to be passed to the database. Here's my code:

```
string insertString = String.Format(
    @"INSERT INTO upload_history (field1, field2, field3) 
    VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')",
    varField1, varField2, varField3);
```

I used single quotes around the variable placeholders so that the database would properly accept a string value. However, if NULL is passed, it ends up going into the database as the string "NULL".

Is there a way I can leave the single quotes out of the InsertCommand string and conditionally add single quotes to my variables?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't concatenate the string (`string.Format`) - use parameters (`@p1` etc) - then you can pass `DBNull.Value` to mean null to SQL Server

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO upload_history (field1, field2, field3) 
   VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", (object)someVar ?? DBNull.Value);
//...
```

This also protects you from SQL injection

Comment: I get the following error when using "someVar ?? DBNull.Value" like above: "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands for type string and System.DBNull" Any thoughts on how this would work with a string?

Comment: @buzzzzjay add a `(object)` in front of either of them.

Answer (score 5):

Concentating the string with String.Format might be a big security risk (SQL Injection), and also problematic if you want to insert the ' character.

Solution:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO upload_history (field1, field2, field3) " +
    "VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", varField1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", varField2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", varField3);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Also a great answer but Marc beat you to it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of answering the question as it was asked, and being fully aware that refactoring the code to paramaterizing the queries is the correct solution, you could write a function that returns either a single-quoted string or a non-quoted NULL string value, then remove the single-quotes from the query string.

```
string insertString = String.Format(    @"INSERT INTO upload_history (field1, field2, field3)     VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2})",    ToStringorNull(varField1), ToStringorNull(varField2), ToStringorNull(varField3));
```

If you are using VS 2008 you could even implement it as an extension method.

```
string insertString = String.Format(    @"INSERT INTO upload_history (field1, field2, field3)     VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2})",    varField1.ToStringorNull, varField2.ToStringorNull, varField3.ToStringorNull);
```

I'll leave creating the ToStringorNull function to you - it isn't hard :-)